# jq: Selecting parent keys based on child array contents

Tags: json, shell, jq

Consider the following `file.json` where `"x"` is a known string. Two questions:

1. I want to obtain a list of all the unique values in the child arrays. What I have is `jq -r '.x[][] file.json | sort | uniq`. Is there a native solution?
2. I want to choose keys `"a"` and `"c"` based on the fact that they both have `"3"` in their respective child arrays. How do I go about that? I can get the child arrays with `"3"` in them with `jq -r '.x[] | select(index("3") >= 0)' file.json` but I need access to the parent key.

```
{
  "x": {
    "a": [
      "2",
      "3"
    ],
    "b": [
      "1",
      "2"
    ],
    "c": [
      "3",
      "4"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: (1) - Easy native solution is just to put all your values in as keys in a single object, and then list those keys; that gets you deduplication "for free".

Comment: (2) Instead of using `.x[] | select`, consider `.x | to_entries | select`; you can make your select operate only on the `.value` part but you avoid throwing away the `.key` part.

Comment: BTW, each Stack Overflow question is supposed to have _only one_ underlying question; otherwise we can get into messy situations where half your question breaks the rules (duplicates prior questions, &c) but the other half doesn't, or where a given person is prepared to answer only one side but not the other, or different answers handle different parts so you can't unambiguously award a best-answer checkbox to one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

2. `jq -r '.x | with_entries(select(.value | index("3"))) | keys[]'` seems to do the trick.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For the first, getting the unique values of the child arrays:

```bash
$ jq '[.x | to_entries[] | .value] | flatten | unique' input.json
[
  "1",
  "2",
  "3",
  "4"
]
```

or if you want the results one element per line instead of as JSON:

```bash
jq -r '[.x | to_entries[] | .value] | flatten | unique[]' input.json
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. I want to obtain a list of all the unique values in the child arrays. What I have is `jq -r '.x[][] file.json | sort | uniq`. Is there a native solution?

Yes, jq has its own `unique` filter  (which also sorts its input automatically). Collect all the items with `[…]` into a single array before using it.

```bash
jq -r '[.x[][]] | unique[]' file.json
```

```
1
2
3
4
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/9-_UwXN2-Un)

---

> 2. I want to choose keys `"a"` and `"c"` based on the fact that they both have `"3"` in their respective child arrays. How do I go about that? I can get the child arrays with `"3"` in them with `jq -r '.x[] | select(index("3") >= 0)' file.json` but I need access to the parent key.

You could iterate over the (sorted) `keys` (use `keys_unsorted` instead if you want the original order), and use `IN` (which is just a shortcut to `any` using `==` as comparator) to `select` by containedness.

```bash
jq '.x | keys[] as $k | select(IN(.[$k][]; "3")) | $k' file.json
```

```
a
c
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/FEujiOx_ovF)

Answer (score 0):

I want to elaborate on the second question as [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77095421/84940) is already a good answer to the first question.

You were quite close on the second one. If you use the update operator (`|=`) instead of the filter operator (`|`), you can get the original JSON with objects for the keys you need:

```
FILTER: .x[] |= select(index("3") >= 0)

RESULT: {"x":{"a":["2","3"],"c":["3","4"]}}
```

Now, say, you only want the objects `a` and `c`, add the trailing `.[]`

```
FILTER: .x[] |= select(index("3") >= 0) | .[]

RESULT: {"a":["2","3"],"c":["3","4"]}
```

Now, say, you only want the said keys alone ([demo](https://jqplay.org/s/QCLwlpcDb0d)):

```
FILTER: .x[] |= select(index("3") >= 0) | .[] | keys

RESULT: ["a","c"]
```